# Magento 2: How can I use "import product data" functionality though REST API/Postman?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, import, import-products

I want to use import functionality in magento 2 (image below) from POSTMAN or my application.
Is there any endpoint available for the same?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Magento Products API? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/create-simple-products.html

Comment: @AbdulPathan I know about this API. But this is not what I am looking for. I want to get the data loaded through csv file.

Comment: I dont think there would be any API since importing is a time consuming process which may lead to timeout for a API call. The better approach would be to use *Scheduled Import* of Magento. https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-scheduled-import-export.html

Comment: @AbdulPathan Which version of magento does have it? I am using version 2.3.5 which does not have the option of scheduled import/export. Is there any way to enable this feature?

Comment: That is because you are on Open Source Edition. Its available for Commerce Edition. You can refer a free plugin https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree or create similar one to fulfill your need. Thanks